# Set chunk_output_type to console removes output from notebook

Tags: r, markdown

I use the `chunk_output_type: console` option because it keeps the code folded upon execution. It turns out doing so removes the output from the knitted notebook as well.

Is there a way so that it appears in the notebook, just not inline. Currently my header reads:

```
output:
  html_notebook:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    theme: united
  html_document:
    toc: true
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
```